# bootstrapping node from chef server failing with SSH error

Tags: chef-infra

I run this command to bootstrap node with chef server which will install chef-client on the node.

```
[root@ip-172-31-23-178 chef-repo]# knife bootstrap 172.31.20.187 --ssh-user ec2-user --sudo -i node1.key.pem -N  node1
```

Expectation: Connection established successfully and chef client installed on the node.

But it fails with below error:

```
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:31: warning: already initialized constant Chef::Knife::Bootstrap::SUPPORTED_CONNECTION_PROTOCOLS
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:31: warning: previous definition of SUPPORTED_CONNECTION_PROTOCOLS was here
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant Chef::Knife::Bootstrap::WINRM_AUTH_PROTOCOL_LIST
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:32: warning: previous definition of WINRM_AUTH_PROTOCOL_LIST was here
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:350: warning: already initialized constant Chef::Knife::Bootstrap::DEPRECATED_FLAGS
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:350: warning: previous definition of DEPRECATED_FLAGS was here
WARNING: You provided --ssh-user. This flag is deprecated. Please use '--connection-user USERNAME' instead.
Node node1 exists, overwrite it? (Y/N) Y
Client node1 exists, overwrite it? (Y/N) Y
Creating new client for node1
Creating new node for node1
Connecting to 172.31.20.187
WARN: [SSH] PTY requested: stderr will be merged into stdout
The authenticity of host '172.31.20.187 ()' can't be established.
fingerprint is SHA256:D8xTTFWkuLv3KUaJWCRjzzAl5Li2XJRlKsaQGux/jWA.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting
? (Y/N) Y
WARN: [SSH] PTY requested: stderr will be merged into stdout
WARN: [SSH] connection failed, terminating (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user ec2-user@172.31.20.187>)
ERROR: Train::Transports::SSHFailed: SSH session could not be established
[root@ip-172-31-23-178 chef-repo]#
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. As the error says `Authentication failed for user ec2-user`, you should ensure that you are able to SSH to the machine with the username and SSH key.

Comment: yes @seshadei i am able to ssh to the machine  with the username and SSH key.

Comment: This is definitely SSH authentication issue. Another clue in the warning `Please use '--connection-user USERNAME'`. You could try this.

Comment: Did you try to ssh to the target server from the same machine and with the same key (node1.key.pem) you try to `knife bootstrap` from?